# GridView showing complete datasource as well as BoundFields

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datasource, boundfield

What I want to do is just display a few specific columns from my data source on my gridview, but for some reason I'm seeing first the boundfields that I want, followed by every column in the data source.

```
            <asp:GridView DataSourceId="dsTasks" ID="TasksGridView" runat="server">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="field1" HeaderText="field1" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="field2" HeaderText="field2" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="field3" HeaderText="field3" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="field4" HeaderText="field4" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="field5" HeaderText="field5" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="field6" HeaderText="field6" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="field7" HeaderText="field7" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

and here is my code for the datasource, just in case thats where it is

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="dsTasks" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="name=Entities" DefaultContainerName="Entities" 
            EnableFlattening="false" EntitySetName="Tasks" ></asp:EntityDataSource>
```

Sorry if this is a stupid question...I'm fairly new to .NET in general (try a week)

Also, as a side question, would it be better for me to bind the data this way, or do it in the code-behind on page_load?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set [`AutoGenerateColumns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogeneratecolumns.aspx) to `false`

```
<asp:GridView AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataSourceId="dsTasks" ...
```

Personally, I prefer binding from markup than from code when and where it's possible.

Comment: and there's one of those "I feel like an idiot" moments. Thanks!

Comment: @Jordan Don't feel bad. Everybody goes through something like this when learning something new.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to set autogeneratecolumn to false for the gridview